# What is final in Swift

Tags: swift

A newbie question.

I'm reading swift documentation [AccessControl](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html). It says there are 5 access specifiers.

- `Open`
- `Public`
- `Internal`
- `File-private`
- `Private`

I thought `Final` is also an access specifier. If not what is it? And can someone give link to the documentation?

Comment: when it is "final" (whether in a class or method) it means no other sub-classes/methods  can alter(overrideen) that class/method

Comment: Both answers explain what `final` is, and the first one has a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an Access Control Specifier, it's a Declaration Modifier.

> **final**
>
> Apply this modifier to a class or to a property, method, or subscript member of a class. It’s applied to a class to indicate that the class can’t be subclassed. It’s applied to a property, method, or subscript of a class to indicate that a class member can’t be overridden in any subclass.

Source: [Swift Language Reference - Declaration – Declaration Modifiers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID381)